# Using AJAX with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use AJAX with a basic example, but the result does not print on the screen. I already looked in the console and there is the correct result, but it keeps printing only the number 10.

I have the following view.

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>

<%= form_tag("/welcome/index",remote: true) do %>
<div id="slider-range-min" ></div>
<p>
<label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
<%= text_field_tag "amount"%>
</p>

<%= submit_tag "Berechnen" %>
<%end%>

output:<%= @out %>

<script>
$(function() {

$( "‪#‎slider‬-range-min" ).slider({
range: "min",
value: 37,
min: 1,
max: 700,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "‪#‎amount‬" ).val( ui.value );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );

});
</script>
```

And this is my controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  input = params[:amount].to_i
  @out = input + 10    
  end
end
```

Comment: Which console, the javascript console or the rails console?

Comment: Javascript console and Rails. There the result is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The `<%= @out %>` is only evaluated once, when the html page was created the first time.

From the ["Working with JavaScript" Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for)

"You probably don't want to just sit there with a filled out , though. You probably want to do something upon a successful submission. To do that, bind to the ajax:success event. On failure, use ajax:error....."
Looks like the situation you described. You need to write an ajax:success handler to put the data somehwere on your page.